# javascript replace string/html from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, string

I try to create a system replacement for ToolTip.

I already create a version but its not quite optimal (search a better way to do it)

here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/forX/Lwgrug24/

I create a dictionary (array[key]->value). the array is order by length of the key.

each key is a word or an expression, the value is the definition of the expression.

So, I replace the expression by a span (could/should be a div). The span is used for the tooltip (I use the data-title as tooltip text).

because some word is reused in expression, I need to remove expression already with tooltip (in real life think of father/grandfather, you dont want the definition of father inside grandfather). For replacement I use a ramdom value. That's the worst of this code.

You could make comment or post a new way to do it. maybe someone already did it.

---

Clarification :

I think my way to do it is wrong by using a string for replacement. Or it could be more secure. How should I do it?

---

html :

```
<div class="container">
    one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
</div>
```

javascript :

```
    $(function() {  
     var list = [
    {'k':'one two three four five','v':'First five number.'},
    {'k':'four five six seven','v':'middle number.'},
    {'k':'six seven eight','v':'second middle number.'},
    {'k':'two','v':'number two.'},
    {'k':'six','v':'number six.'},
    {'k':'ten','v':'number ten.'}
];     

$(".container").each(function(){

    var replacement = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

        var val = list[i];                  

        var rString = randomString(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');           

        replacement[rString + "_k"] = htmlEncode(val["k"]);                
        replacement[rString + "_v"] = htmlEncode(val["v"]);

        var re = new RegExp("(" + val["k"] + ")","g");

        $(":contains('" + val["k"] + "')",$(this).parent()).html(function(_, html) {

            var newItem = '<span class="itemWithDescription" '
                + 'data-title="' + rString + "_v" + '">' 
                + rString + "_k"
                + '</span>';

           return  html.replace(re, newItem);
        });         
    }

    for (var k in replacement){ 
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(k,replacement[k]));
        console.log("Key is " + k + ", value is : " + replacement[k]);
    }       
});


 $(document).tooltip({
    items:'.itemWithDescription',
    tooltipClass:'Tip',
    content: function(){
        var title = $(this).attr("data-title");
        if (title == ""){
            title = $(this).attr("title");  //custom tooltips
        }
        return title;
    }


});


 });

function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}

function htmlEncode(value){
    //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
    //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

---

I added a little thing. on the random function, I put a | and } for every char, its bigger but there's not much chance to have a conflic with an expression.

```
  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += '|' + ( chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))] ) + '}' ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/forX/Lwgrug24/3/

Comment: its not clear what your question is, please clarify.

Comment: I think my way to do it is wrong by using a string for replacement. Or it could be more secure. How should I do it?

Comment: please, if you asked to close the post, add a comment why. I still dont know what to do with my problem.